# how to store a date in database through string?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to store  a date in my database. I have added two keys values in web.config. I have used `keyFinancialYr` and `keyFinancialQtr` in my code behind to store those values in my database in two column as financial year and financial quarter. I can store `keyFinancialQtr` value in my database. But when i try to store `keyFinancialYr` value it gives error. like this "An exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot convert value '-2018' to Type: System.DateTime."

`web.config`-

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="keyFinancialYr" value="2018-01-01" />

  <add key="keyFinancialQtr" value="1" />
</appSettings>
```

code behind-

```
    DateTime x = Convert.ToDateTime(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyFinancialYr"]);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyFinancialQtr"]);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

        //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
        dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[9] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
              new DataColumn("Banks", typeof(string)),
               new DataColumn("Crop Loan", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Water Resources", typeof(decimal)),
                 new DataColumn("Farm Mechanisation", typeof(int)),
                  new DataColumn("Plantation & Horticulture", typeof(decimal)),
            new DataColumn("Forestry & Wasteland Dev.", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Financial_Quarter", typeof(int),y.ToString()),
            new DataColumn("Financial_yr",typeof(DateTime),x.ToShortDateString())
             });
```

Comment: You need to include the error otherwise nobody will have a clue. It's like phoning a garage and saying "there is *something* wrong with my car"

Comment: Where is error msg? where is query? Shall we guess that?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot convert value '-2018' to Type: System.DateTime.

Comment: can you please edit the question again and post the exception message that you are getting while storing the keyFinancialYr

Comment: The third parameter of the DataColumn constructor is the expression to be used to calculate the value of the column. It is not the value of the column (if this concept has any sense)

Comment: I can not get you

Comment: Why the `sql-server` tag? This code doesn't connect to the database at all. It's only a DataTable with invalid column specifications.

Comment: what is the data type of Financial_yr in your database

Comment: @HAPPYsukh when you create a DataTable you define the columns first, then you load the data into the rows. You *don't* put data into the columns. What are you trying to do with `new DataColumn("Financial_yr",typeof(DateTime),x.ToShortDateString())` ? Hard-code a value? Set all rows to the same value? Set a header?

Comment: What value do you have in variable `x` when you get the exception?

Comment: @HAPPYsukh also post the *full* exception, as returned by `Exception.ToString()`. The full exception string contains the call stack which shows where exactly the exception was thrown. Posting only the message without explaining where the error was thrown doesn't help

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it doesn't matter. Whatever it is, it's going to be wrong. The third parameter is the *expression* for a computed column. A date string is definitely not a valid expression, especially a localized short date string

Comment: @Panagiotis you are right. `x.ToShortDateString()` will result in `01-01-2018` which results in "-2018" as the it becomes expression and evaluates as math formula. And "-2018" is surely not a valid dateTime value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HAPPYsukh,

The constructor of DataColumn you are using expects a expression as third parameter. When you pass `x.ToShortDateString()` to it, it will result in `01-01-2018` which results in "-2018" as the it becomes expression and evaluates as math formula. And "-2018" is surely not a valid dateTime value.

Same applies to `Financial_Quarter` column too.

If you want to set `x` as a default value for the column `Financial_yr` you should set it once the column is created.

You can set `DefaultValue` properties of both the columns as following while adding them to the columns collection of the table.

```
var financialQtrColumn = new DataColumn("Financial_Quarter", typeof(int)) { DefaultValue = y };
var financialYearColumn = new DataColumn("Financial_yr", typeof(DateTime)) { DefaultValue = x };
//[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(
    new DataColumn[9] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Banks", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Crop Loan", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Water Resources", typeof(decimal)),
    new DataColumn("Farm Mechanisation", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Plantation & Horticulture", typeof(decimal)),
    new DataColumn("Forestry & Wasteland Dev.", typeof(int)),
    financialQtrColumn,
    financialYearColumn
});
```

I have just posted the lines of code which you need to change.

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 3rd argument of the [DataColumn Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bdkcbb6(v=vs.110).aspx) is an expression, rather than interpreting your string as a date, it taking it as a formula, i.e.

```
1 - 1 - 2018 = -2018
```

And `-2018` is not a valid date. You need to add single quotes either side of your date to make sure it is interpreted a literal:

```
new DataColumn("Financial_yr", typeof(DateTime), "'" + x.ToShortDateString() + "'")
```

An alternative would be to use the [DefaultValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) Property.

```
new DataColumn("Financial_yr", typeof(DateTime)) { DefaultValue = x}
```

Comment: I'd guess the OP wants to hard-code the date colum, not set a default. Simply quoting the original string should work in this case